# Please translate the image (Characters identified: 虾炒饭（大）)

Tags: translation, character-identification

Can someone explain the symbol at the end... the symbol that looks like breasts?

> [image]

Comment: Are they just trying to say the serving size of the 虾炒饭 is one person (人)?

Comment: You have shown no effort on this. You even refuse to tell people it's a menu.

Comment: He just wanted to show some optical illusions that  looks like breasts, he knew full well that it is  (大) missing a middle stoke. remind me of a neon signs that said "信耶蘇得永生" became ""信耶蘇得水牛" after a few neon tubes burned out

Answer (score 5):

It is 虾炒飯（大）. The one stoke in the middle  had faded out, the ink just fell off

Appearnently it is  “Shrimp fried rice (large)” on a menu

Comment: Now that I look again the missing stroke is so obvious.  Nice catch.

Comment: Maybe the OP, a female, (Anna?), thought, (or trying to be funny), that the "large breast" stands for "large" serving of shrimp fried rice? Give her the benefit of the doubt.